# como mostrar la cantidad de visitas que tiene una página

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Quiero mostrar la cantidad de visitas que tiene una página en la miniatura de la página principal, al estilo youtube, no se como llamar esa clase para que muestre la cantidad de visitas en cualquier lado que yo quiera, este es el codigo:

```
<td class="K3JSBVB-o-a K3JSBVB-o-c K3JSBVB-o-j" valign="top" align="right">
    <div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-433">
        <span class="K3JSBVB-c-f">196</span>
        <span class="K3JSBVB-s-d" title="Las veces que se ha visto"></span>
    </div>
</td>
```

y que se vayan actualizando en tiempo real.

Comment: Que haz investigado o que código tienes hasta ahora? Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, Pero para que sea realmente en tiempo real puedes usar https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Usas Base de Datos? usas PHP u otro lenguaje de programación? o solo es una página con htm, js y css?